# Presence - absent dataset

Tags: r

I'm trying to produce a absence and presence dataset within R to use for a subsequent model. I have multiple csv sheets with locations on and vegetation rasters that match these locations. I need to produce a presence absence dataset to model habitat selection. I have got this far with the script:

```
setwd("~/Masters/Research Project/GIS/GIS_Focal_Raster")    
library(raster)    

## import the raster layer used as the mask                            ##

absent<-raster("Veg_B2.tif")    
mask<-raster(absent)    

present<-read.csv("B2_Lon_Lat.csv")    
present    

## select 500 random points                                            ##
## set seed to assure that the examples will always have the same      ##
## random sample.                                                      ##

library(dismo)    
set.seed(1963)     
bg<-randomPoints(mask,500)     

## set up the plotting area for two maps                               ##
par(mfrow=c(1,2))     
plot(!is.na(mask),legend=FALSE,main="random")     
points(bg,cex=0.5)     

## repeat the sampling, but limit the area of sampling using a spatial ##
## extent                                                              ##

library(raster)     
library(extent)    

r<-raster("Veg_B2.tif")    
e<-extent(r)     

bg2<-randomPoints(mask,50,ext=e)     
plot(!is.na(mask),legend=FALSE)    
plot(e,add=TRUE,col='red')     
points(bg2,cex=0.5)     

## pseudo-absence points                                               ##

library(rgdal)     
present<-read.csv("B2_Lon_Lat.csv")      
coordinates(present)=~lon+lat
```

but then I come up with the error

> coordinates(present)=~lon+lat
>   Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'lon' not found
>   Any suggestions how to continue?

Comment: Do you have a column in `present` called `lon`? Please show `dput(head(present))`

Comment: Thank you sorry feel like this may have been a very silly question now have changed lon to Longitude (heading in my data) and all has worked. Many thanks